# Cannot attach GPU to Google Cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, gcloud

I have a n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory) instance on Google Cloud with a 600GB standard persistent disk attached to it. It works normally, until I try to attach a GPU (NVIDIA Tesla K80) to it and restart it. Then I get the following message:

> Starting VM instance "instance_name" failed. Error: The zone
>   'projects_name/zones/us-east1-d' does not have enough
>   resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or
>   try again later.

I've been getting this error for the past two weeks. For a while I assumed that this was an issue with GPUs being occupied by other users on the same zone. So I moved the instance (along attached disk) to a different zone using `gcloud compute instances move` with no difference in the outcome. Cloning the instance on other zone/regions did not change the error either.

But I'm guessing that this is not really a resource issue, since **I am able to create a new instance with the same specs (CPU/GPU/Memory) on the same zone and run it without any problem**.

I was able to attach GPUs to this instance about one or two months ago. But a lot of resizing, and coding has been done since then. So I'm not sure if I have changed some important settings that could be relevant. Does anyone know why this is happening?

What is the recommended solution?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is for lack of resources in the zone. The fact that you can create brand new instances with a GPU means that there is likely enough. This being said, this sounds like an issue on the GCP side. I suggest opening a ticket through the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I created an [Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110711936) for it.

Comment: @JavNoor - that issue link no longer works. Was it resolved?

Comment: Not really. It's been a long time since then but I still encounter issues like this. They haven't fixed. The workaround that I've been using is to make a new VM or keep editing the existing one until somehow magically it begins working.